# C: Is this code snippet correct for left shifting a character array, resting the "nth" bit and setting the 0th bit as 0 or 1 based on a condition?

Tags: c

I have to do this program where i have to use a register which can be anything between 1 to 20 bits long. i could only think of using a character array for this purpose. 
I want to left shift(by 1), reset the nth bit and set or reset the 0th bit depending on a condition. Since i do not know the number of bits until at run time, i am using using malloc to allocate the size of the character array. Please tell me if this is correct

```
// history bits can change from 1 to 20
int historyRegisterSize=(historybits+7)/8;

// allocating memory dynamically
historyRegister=malloc(historyRegisterSize * sizeof(unsigned char));

// Shifting left one bit
    unsigned char *byte;
    int size=historyRegisterSize;
    for( byte =historyRegister; size--; ++byte )
    {
        unsigned char bit = 0;
        if (size>=0)
        {
            bit = byte[1] & (1 << (8 - 1)) ? 1 : 0;
        }
        *byte <<= 1;
        *byte |= bit;
    }

    // Resetting the nth bit 
    historyRegister[0]=historyRegister[0] & 0x7;

     // or should i use this one for resetting?
     //historyRegister[historyRegisterSize-1] &= ~(1 <<(historybits-1));

    // Setting the 0th bit based on a condition
    if(condition)
    {
        historyRegister[historyRegisterSize-1]=historyRegister[historyRegisterSize-1] | 1;
        // or should i use this statement below?
        //historyRegister[0] |= 1 <<0;
    }
    else
    {
    historyRegister[historyRegisterSize-1]=historyRegister[historyRegisterSize-1] & 0xfe;
      // or should i use this statement below?
      //historyRegister[0] &= ~(1 <<0);
    }
```

After doing all this, i want to XOR an unsigned 64 bit integer with my character array(historyRegister) and take the modulus of it. For that i am using this statement

```
// result and var2 and unsigned long variables 
// and size is another unsigned integer.
result=(var1 ^ *(unsigned long int *)historyRegister) % size;
```

Does everything seem correct? My problem is that when I change the number of bits in the character array, an output values seems to remain constant for a range. That is from 1 to 8 bits its the same o/p, from 8 to 16 and then from 16 to 20. Am i going wrong with the Endianness?

Also , it there a better alternative to using character array ?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, each "register" is up to 20 bits long. But a `char` only has 8 bits. So you're gonna need a bigger datatype?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to store 20 bits it would be easier to use an unsigned int or long.
Shifting could then be done by

```
val <<= 1;
```

You could mask off the leftmost bits by

```
val &= ((1u <<n) -1);
```

Comment: could you tell me what the '1u' in the statement is? how do i change it to reset only a particular bit in the unsigned long variable?

Comment: 1u is just "cast as a literal cast to an unsigned type". It might be superfluous, but it is a (good?) habit to to perform all operations on bitmasks on unsigned types.